# CSS Background Image Query

Tags: html, css

I basically have the following class:

```
.sf-sub-indicator {
  background:   url("/abcprod/images/arrows-ffffff.png") no-repeat -10px -100px;
}
```

Is it possible in CSS to set a background image clause to use a hardcoded symbol such as ">" so that instead it uses:

```
.sf-sub-indicator {
  background:   url(">") no-repeat -10px -100px;
}
```

Don't actually want it to use an image but a symbol instead.

Can this be done against a class such as above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no.  You can only set a background to a color or an image.

Comment: ... and the long answer is no longer :)

Comment: The only workaround in strictly CSS would be to set the `content` attribute on a DIV to the symbol (repeated however many times you want, as you can't have it repeat endlessly), then absolutely positioning it so that it appears behind the content.  Not really a valid method.  You'd be better off just making an image of the symbol (which you could do dynamically in PHP using GD).  You can also use a .php file as a CSS file, so you could include it right in the CSS file.

Comment: Thanks to all for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done via url(). inside the bracket should be "url" of image type.

You can do something similar using jquery

```
$(".sf-sub-indicator").each( function() { $(this).html(">" + $(this).html()) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Long answer: Yes. Sort of.

Your most-popular tag is jQuery, so I won't go in depth with the code, but basically you could find the class:

```
var div = $(".sf-sub-indicator")
```

get its dimensions:

```
var height = div.height()` and `var width = div.width()
```

Then you could create an absolutely positioned `div` of that height and width, and place it directly over the original `div`. Then, making sure that the first `div` had no `background-color`, you could give that a higher `z-index` than the new div.

Lastly, fill the new div with `.innerHtml` with your character, and set `overflow=hidden`.

This is a weird request...